# Trying to stream my (very large) json file with ijson - is it formatted wrong?

Tags: python, json, large-data, ijson

I'm trying to stream through a large json file using ijson in python. This is my first time trying this.

my code is really simple right now:

```
with open('file.json', 'rb') as f:
j = ijson.items(f, 'item')

for item in j:
    print('x')
```

This returns a "trailing garbage" error - essentially the 2nd item in the file is considered garbage, i think because of the file format.

My json file is [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/techmap/us-job-postings-from-2023-05-05) from kaggle, and is formatted like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6457879fd1187d621cbbba9c"},"sourceCC":"us",...etc...}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6457879fd1187d621cbddd8a"},"sourceCC":"us",...etc...}
```

It is about 3GB in size, so im unable to open it.

If i use 'multiple_items=True' i believe it considers all the items to be multiple values for the same item, so it does not return any error, but also does not return anything else.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `ijson` is useful when your entire file is a *single* 3GB object; you can get the value associated with the first key, then the second, etc, without having to read the entire object into memory first.

Comment: You can use the `multiple_valuee` option in `ijson` and it will allow you to go through multiple documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not actuall a JSON document. That is a series of JSON documents concatenated using newlines. You don't need `ijson` to read it; you can instead read it line-by-line and use the built-in `json` module:

```
import json

with open('myfile.json') as fd:
  for line in fd:
    obj = json.loads(line)
    # do something with obj here
```